# Increment / decrement button In ExtJS

Tags: button, extjs, textfield, increment, decrement

Is there a button in ExtJS with increment/decrement feature (something like [that](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/HelpResource.ashx?help=WPF&document=img10293.jpg))? I have some numberfields with values that are usually incremented/decremented when edited and this button would be very helpful. Note that it is not critical for me to stick the button to my numberfield, I mean I can handle it as a separate object.

Any bright ideas? Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE: Two narrow buttons sticked together would be a solution too.. Anybody knows how to place two buttons that way in a single grid toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this 3rd party extension...

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/CustomSpinnerWidget.htm

It might require a little debugging as its for ExtJS 3.0, not 3.3

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Ext 4 the NumberField has exactly that behavior (see [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/form/fieldcontainer.html) as one example). This is a change from Ext 3, which required a spinner user extension I believe for such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No, in default package there is no such control. May be as some external package somewhere.